# Z3 RegEx for Int*

Tags: regex, z3

I'm trying to write an assertion that a certain **sequence of integers contains at least 2 occurrences of some integer** (say 8). Here is what I wrote:

```
(declare-const s (Seq Int))
(assert (seq.in.re s
    (re.++
        re.all
        (re.++
            (seq.to.re (seq.unit 8))
            (re.++
                re.all
                (re.++
                    (seq.to.re (seq.unit 8))
                    re.all))))))
```

When I tried to run it I get the following error:

```
(error "line 11 column 11: Sort of function 're.++' does not match the declared type. Given domain: (RegEx (Seq Int)) (RegEx String) ")
```

So I guess `re.all` is defined only for strings? Is there any way to create a **regular expression for all integers**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMTLib type-system is rather weak, and it gets confused when it sees `re.all` as it cannot distinguish between a string regexp and a regexp over some other sequence. And thus you're getting a type-error.

This is anticipated in the SMTLib standard actually, see Section 3.6.4 of http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf

The solution (as described in the standard) is to use an `as` clause to give an explicit type, like this:

```
(define-fun allInt () (RegEx (Seq Int)) (as re.all (RegEx (Seq Int))))

(declare-const s (Seq Int))
(assert (seq.in.re s
    (re.++
        allInt
        (re.++
            (seq.to.re (seq.unit 8))
            (re.++
                allInt
                (re.++
                    (seq.to.re (seq.unit 8))
                    allInt))))))
```

This is a common gotcha for people who expect the system to figure out from context what the actual type should be. But to keep the system simple, designers went for a very simple type system: Each term should be typeable on its own, without any contextual information. In rare cases where this is not possible (such as your use case), they provided the `as` syntax as a means of being explicit about typing.