# How do I concatenate two regexes with the Python Z3 bindings?

Tags: python, regex, z3

I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57455242/2852699) that there's a `re.++` function in the SMTLIB bindings that seems to do what I want. What is its equivalent in the Python bindings? For example:

```py
from z3 import *
r1 = Star(Re('ab'))
r2 = Re('a')
r_concatenated = Re(r1 ++ r2)
```

which would be equivalent to the regex `ab*a`. How do I get `r_concatenated`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer about one minute after posting this question. If you use the [`Concat`](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a4dfadd3cb36aaa827c9202a949a506a4) method it works, although the documentation only mentions bitvectors. So the code would be:

```py
from z3 import *
r1 = Star(Re('ab'))
r2 = Re('a')
r_concatenated = Concat(r1, r2)
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64408788/how-to-concatenate-regular-expressions-in-z3py